# Delete session in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, session-variables

I am using a session_variable as the user_id to get information about the user by querying with the help of the variable. Whenever my user logs in with correct credentials, I create a session variable using:

```
\Session::put('user_id', $user_id);
```

And now I have a condition when the user logs out from the website,so how do I remove the session variable from the session using laravel. I tried something like : `session()->forget('some_data');` which didn't seem to work for me so what should I do to remove all the session variable I have in the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
Session::flush(); // removes all session data

Session::forget('user_id') // Removes a specific variable
```